# Is there a way to reset ubuntu 16.04 server

Tags: server, flask

My fried bought me an ubuntu server 16.04 so that I could upload my flask app on to it. However he bought it from China and only gave me the login details;

```
ssh Fonzi@52.232.108.191
```

and the password. I have been having difficulties uploading the flask app, using virtual environments, as it seems when I install packages with `pip` it is installing it globally not just within my virtual environment.

I am also having difficulties accessing the site via its ip and have installed lots of dependencies that I don't think I need and they are conflicting with each other.

Is there a way for me to reset the server back to its original state?

Comment: If you wish to simply reinstall, then yes. If you have a good backup of the state you wish to revert to, then yes. Otherwise, no.

Comment: @user535733 Don't have a good backup! But don't mind reinstalling as I have nothing in there. But am confused as to where or how I reinstall as it is a live server